# Xamarin, MySQL exception: unable to connect to any specific host

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin, exception

I want to make an simple app that will get data out of remote database and show it on a screen, so first I made a simple console app to test connection and it all works. here's code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=85.10.205.173; PORT=3306; DATABASE=mybasework; UID=neawin; PWD=12345678; old guids=true; Connection Timeout=30;");
        try
        {
            if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM motto", con);
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {                           
                        Console.WriteLine(reader["motto"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

But then when i tried to test connection on my phone it shows that it is unable to connect to the host, here's code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private TextView Textmotto;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Textmotto = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textmotto);
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=85.10.205.173; PORT=3306; DATABASE=mybasework; UID=neawin; PWD=12345678; old guids=true; Connection Timeout=30;");
            try
            {

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    Textmotto.Text = "Success";

                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Textmotto.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think i tried every variation of connectionstring I could, in first program I used mysql.data library and in phone app I used Xamarin.Mysql Nuget Package if that makes any difference. Sorry for english and poor formatting, my first post.

Comment: are you sure that the mobile device can connect to that IP?  Is the firewall blocking the port?

Comment: did you declare internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: Sorry, didint see it earlier, but i figure it out myself, thanks for help tho

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a network issue.  But please, don't do this.  In order to directly connect to a DB, you need to put the password to your db in plain text in your app (even if you encrypt it, the key is in your app).  This is totally insecure, and any script kiddie can own your database.  If you need data from a database, write a webservice and have the webservice access the db, so you never need to have the authentication information leave your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help, I resolved the issue by adding INTERNET permission in my manifest as suggested by Vladyslav.